# Can't find class with name as the migrated table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I started a project with Laravel, I made a migration:

```
Schema::create('confirmations', function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->string('email')->index();
     $table->string('token')->index();
     $table->boolean('activated');
     $table->timestamp('created_at')->nullable();
});
```

and I tried to use it like that:

```
    Confirmation::create([
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'token' => Str::random(60),
    ]);
```

I see error:

> Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Confirmation' not found

I use also scaffolded User migration and it works, what should I do to make my Table work too?

@edit: I didn't mean to paste Userr error, just Confirmation, fixed now

Comment: when does this error shows up ? during migration ?

Comment: no, migration is OK, I try to add confirmation on register page and when I use it this error pops up

Comment: can you post your controller code where this error occurs ?

Comment: where is `Userr` model in your project ? inside App ?or some other directory ?

Comment: where is the Confirmation class defined?

Comment: Create Confirmation model first at _App_ directory. If not exist then create is. You can take model example from `App/User.php`. Let me know if this is not your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, you would need to import the `Userr` class.
Assuming, you have `Userr` class inside app directory, add following line to your Controller.

```
use App/Userr;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Controller where you wrote this code

```
Confirmation::create([
    'email' => $data['email'],
    'token' => Str::random(60),
]);
```

in that same file write below code in the top of the file

```
use App\Confirmation
```